# Moral of the queen and the dog folk tale?

Tags: story-identification, sexuality

When I was 10 years old, I heard my family talking about a story that went like this:

There is a kingdom with a queen who engages in an illicit affair with a dog while the king is away, resulting in the birth of a child. The minister discovers this secret and faces a moral dilemma about whether to reveal the truth to the king.

My mom noticed me hearing their talk and they stopped it abruptly as the topic was deemed inappropriate or sensitive for a young listener.

Can you please help me understand what's the story about and the moral? I just want to know if there is a collection of stories like this, to understand the author's philosophy and the time period in which it was written.

Comment: Well, human-dog hybrids are certainly fantastical, but the question here does not seem to be about identifying the story (which would be within the site's scope) but rather explaining what it is about (which is too broad). Also the list in the question is a little strange, particularly since you say you want to know what the story is about, but then give its plot and themes. It makes me think "homework question" or "language model."

Comment: In particular, "As the story is a folk tale, its interpretation and significance may vary depending on cultural and regional contexts" seems like pure ChatGPT to me. Did you try to get it to answer the question and then post the response into this question?

Comment: Oops, I voted to close but mistakenly chose "opinion based". My actual reason is: what is the fantastical element here? That a dog was a human's father? The biological aspect doesn't seem to be played up for importance, if this is mostly a fable about honesty and loyalty with barely any sf&f elements, it seems it's off-topic here.

Comment: @AndresF. - Unless I'm seriously misremembering my biology lessons, a woman bearing a dog's baby would definitely make this a fantasy *of some description*.

Comment: @Valorum agreed, but depends on the degree of importance. If it's just waved aside and not an integral part of the story (i.e. if trust/betrayal is the real point), then is this even a fantasy story? Is the dog being the "father" THE key aspect here? Is this question about a fantasy aspect of the story?

Comment: We have a [mythology.se] site. I can't find any reference to this story with a quick search, but it may be worth trying there if we don't come-up with anything. Remember if you post this there to delete this first so as to avoid cross-site duplication.

Comment: @Adamant yeah  used chatgpt to comprehend it better for understanding of the audience , I just wanted to know is there a collection of stories like this , to understand the philosophy behind the author and the time period in which it was written and so on  .

Comment: The 2nd, 4th, and 5th paragraphs sound like AI generated BS that add nothing to your question. Suggest you remove them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble agreed! I made an effort at removing most GPT generated garbage and tried to narrow this down to a clear question (still think this is off-topic for scifi.se, but I seem to be outvoted on that front... oh, well).